# dpkg error. Getting these error while instaling npm in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python-2.7, npm, dpkg

Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.16-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: 64: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 installed python2.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2-minimal:
 python2-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.16-1~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python2-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I have used the sudo apt install npm command

Comment: Please ask at Ubuntu forum, support or Q&A side.